# Dual-Boot Problem with Pre-Installed Windows 8.1 & Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, grub-efi

I do understand similar questions already exist. Yet mine seems to be a problem that despite trying hard to address, I haven't been able to solve. Despite having a working Ubuntu LTs 14.04 installation on my dual-booted laptop, the GRUB loader menu does not appear. It boots straight into Windows 8.1. I've tried the existing solutions such as using Boot Repair, or running the bcdedit command in Windows and the like.
Mine is a HP Laptop with 64-bit processor.
I've made the following observations:
1. I don't have the 'Boot from EFI file' option listed in my BIOS boot order menu. It only has 'OS Boot Manager' that defaults to the Windows bootloader.
2. The Secure Boot is disabled.
3. I had formatted and re-installed my Ubuntu over an earlier installation (same version) owing to me screwing up the OS by installing too many packages. The installation completed successfully, yet I can't access the GRUB menu at the startup. The Linux can only be accessed by doing Shift+Restart from Windows side-bar and then choosing ubuntu as the boot device.
4. The paste bin URL generated by Boot-Repair is as follows:
[The Paste-Bin Boot-Repair URL](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16147702)

It would be great if someone can help me out figuring how to get back to my feet with Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: HP along with Sony and some others violate UEFI spec. Spec says not to use description as part of boot and only valid description is "Windows Boot Loader". But all UEFI boot a fallback or hard drive boot entry, so the work around is to make that really be shimx64.efi and boot the hard drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 Boot-Repair should have copied it, but you need to boot a hard drive UEFI entry. IF you want rEFInd to work you copy its boot file to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi instead of shimx64.efi.

Answer (score 0):

HP UEFI does not allow to boot Ubuntu directly.
The workaround is that: On boot quickly press the **F9** key repeatedly. Then a screen will appear showing the various bootloaders available. 
If this screen does not appear try **Fn+F9**, else press **escape** and you will see a sceen with options to boot from EFI file or choose bootloader.

If the Ubuntu options are not available, boot from a live ISO and check your EFI partition to see if it has a folder named **Ubuntu** in it.

If the F9 option does work, there will be two options for Ubuntu. You can select any one. One just points to the shim.efi(Secure boot) and the other just points to the bootx64.efi.

Please upvote if it helped.